# Rails3.1 upgrade causing NoMethodError on cookies.signed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've run into some pretty strange problems regarding the cookie store in an app I've upgraded from Rails 3.0.10 to Rails 3.1.

I can isolate the failing specs to this:

```
class TestController
  before_filter :check_cookie

  def index; end

  private

  def check_cookie
    if cookies.signed.present?
       cookies.delete(:test)
    end
  end
end
```

All specs invoking the check_cookie filter fail with an error message like:

```
NoMethodError:
  You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
  You might have expected an instance of Array.
  The error occurred while evaluating nil.delete

# ./app/controllers/test_controller.rb:10:in `check_cookie'
```

To debug further I've tried adding a statement to output `cookies.signed` before trying to invoke `delete`:

```
if cookies.signed.present?
    puts "Knock, knock? #{cookies.signed.respond_to?(:delete)}"
    ...
```

This outputs "true", but the specs still fail.

Running Rails 3.1.0 with Rspec 2.6.0.

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try checking to see if the cookie exists before deleting it:

```
if cookies.signed.present? && cookies.has_key?(:test)
   cookies.delete(:test)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling delete on cookies, but you are inpecting whether cookies.signed.respond_to? :delete, may be you should check cookies.respond_to? :delete?